# what is the meaning '.*'?

Tags: sql, regex

EX:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM   station
WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$'
```

Comment: It's a REGEXP is short for "regular expression", which is a text matching language. https://dataschool.com/how-to-teach-people-sql/how-regex-works-in-sql/

Comment: A good place to start: [What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 2):

This is a Regular Expression (Regex for short).
It is a more or less simple way of performing very complex and versatile searches over text.
In this case, the dot (`.`) means "any character", and the asterisk (`*`) means "any times", from none to "infinite".
So, any of thouse examples whould be a positive match (any number of any characters, including no charachter):

```
ae
afu
adfo
efhhha
ahjhjfgjdha
azdgsdfhshsdfgsu
(etc)..
```

The following web gives a nice visual explanation of regexs:
https://www.dcode.fr/regular-expression-analyser

[image: visual explanation of regex]